# Which library to import in micropython to transmit IR code on esp8266?

Tags: nodemcu, micropython

I am trying to migrate my code that is written in C++ syntax to  python syntax. Now my issue is, I am not able to find the right library to import in REPL.

I am trying to transmit RC6 data of length 24. In original code, I have include

```
#include <IRremoteESP8266.h>
#include <IRsend.h>
//some code
const uint16_t kIrLed = 4;  // ESP GPIO pin to use. Recommended: 4 (D2).
IRsend irsend(kIrLed);  // Set the GPIO to be used to sending the message.
//some more code
ir.**sendRC6**([code] ,[length]);
```

Please suggest which library to import, such that I can send the hex data on GPIO D2.

Thanks and Regards,
Shariq